# Strip Map Index Data driven pages not creating in order

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, data-driven-pages, strip-map

I have a map book I am trying to create from a line that i pieced together from 2 different feature classes.  I combined the 2 different lines, and made sure my end vertex is at the end of the line, but my map book is still placing the pages out of order.  I have tried creating the line several different ways, and was wondering if there is something I am missing.  I have tried it about 5 different times and it is not working.  I have created a strip map index off of this line before, and have not run into this problem.

To reference, the line is only one segment, and the end vertex is at the end of the line, there are no segments that cross over each other.

Comment: I think you should Repair Geometry your feature class, and if the problem persists then [edit] your question to show pictures of the line feature class and the order the map sheets were created in, as well as the attribute table of the line feature class.